# Angular: Capability of automatic change detection and update view

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a table in which I'm displaying Json object values and have a model in which I can add new data and later I'm displaying those values in the table.

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of icDataToDisplay.icdata; let icIndex=index">
       <td [ngClass]="editMode && clickedRowIndex === icIndex? 'edit-enabled': ''">{{row.Device_Type}}</td>
       <td [ngClass]="editMode && clickedRowIndex === icIndex? 'edit-enabled-category': ''">{{row.Device_Model}}</td>
       <td [ngClass]="editMode && clickedRowIndex === icIndex? 'enabled-recommendation': ''">
            <span *ngIf="editMode && clickedRowIndex !== icIndex">{{row.Recommended_Software_Version}}</span>
            <span *ngIf="!editMode && clickedRowIndex !== icIndex">{{row.Recommended_Software_Version}}</span>
            <input type="text" class="enabled-hw" [(ngModel)]="row.Recommended_Software_Version" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event, 'Recommended_Software_Version')"
                                    *ngIf="editMode && clickedRowIndex === icIndex" />
       </td>


    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Component

```
public addSoftwareIcData() {
        this.configManagementService.postIcData(this.clickedProductFamily,
            '', this.icDataObject, 'Software').
            subscribe((response) => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    this.closeAddIcModal();
                    this.myData = 'IC data added successfully.';
                    this.icDataList = response;
                    this.ref.markForCheck();
                } else if (response.status === 304) {
                    this.info = response.message;
                }
            });
    }
```

In the modal, it's a POST api call and and the response will have the newly added data along with old data. I'm reassigning the api data icDataToDisplay.icdata for rendering.

Problem is view is not getting updated even though icDataToDisplay.icdata value got changed. Why Angular is not performing automatic change detection? I tried with this.ref.markForCheck(); change detector of Angular but it's not working. Please suggest

Comment: can you share you component

Comment: @Vikas Yeah I added

Comment: My guess is that the DOM is already getting rendered by the time the response is back. Try using [async](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).

Comment: Can you show how and where are you re-assigning the response to `icDataToDisplay`?